# Testing email from shell Cakephp 3.x

Tags: shell, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I want to make test cases, with phpunit and cakephp 3.x, shell that send email. This is my function into shell:

```
class CompaniesShellTest extends TestCase
{
    public function monthlySubscription()
    {
      /* .... */

          $email = new Email('staff');
          try {

              $email->template('Companies.alert_renew_success', 'base')
                  ->theme('Backend')
                  ->emailFormat('html')
                  ->profile(['ElasticMail' => ['channel' => ['alert_renew_success']]])
                  ->to($user->username)
                  //->to('dario@example.com')
                  ->subject('Eseguito rinnovo mensile abbonamento')
                  ->viewVars(['company' => $company, 'user' => $user])
                  ->send();
          } catch (Exception $e) {
              debug($e);
          }

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

In my testing class i have this functions

```
/**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->io = $this->getMockBuilder('Cake\Console\ConsoleIo')->getMock();
    $this->CompaniesShell = new CompaniesShell($this->io);
}
/**
 * tearDown method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function tearDown()
{
    unset($this->CompaniesShell);
    parent::tearDown();
}
/**
 * Test monthlySubscription method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testMonthlySubscription()
{
   $email = $this->getMock('Cake\Mailer\Email', array('subject', 'from', 'to', 'send'));

    $email->expects($this->exactly(3))->method('send')->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $this->CompaniesShell->MonthlySubscription();
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Any ideas? I want to check if the mails are successfully sent and how many times.

Answer (score 3):

The way you wrote your code won't work.

```
$email = new Email('staff');
```

And:

```
$email = $this->getMock('Cake\Mailer\Email', array('subject', 'from', 'to', 'send'));
```

How do you expect the class you call to magically replace the $email variable with your mock object? You'll need to refactor your code.

This is how I would do it:

First [implement a custom mailer](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails) like SubscriptionMailer. Put your mail code into this mailer class. That makes sure you have nice separated and reuseable code.

```
public function getMailer() {
    return new SubscriptionMailer();
}
```

In your test mock the getMailer() method of your shell and return your email mock.

```
$mockShell->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getMailer')
    ->will($this->returnValue($mailerMock));
```

You can then do the expectation you already have.

```
$email->expects($this->exactly(3))->method('send')->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

Also depending on what your shell method is doing, maybe it is better to send the email in the afterSave callback (again using the custom mailer class) of a model object (table) that is processing the data from your shell. Check the example [at the end of this page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails).